# invariant probleme and implicit move constructor

Tags: c++, move

I read this article [cppnext implicit move](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/10/implicit-move-must-go/) but I didn't understand this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct X
{
    // invariant: v.size() == 5
    X() : v(5) {}

    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    }

 private:    
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> y;
    y.push_back(X()); // X() rvalue: copied in C++03, moved in C++0x
}
```

Under MSVC2010 there is no bug at runtime... Can anyone help me?

In this article there is this sentence :

> The key problem here is that in C++03, X had an invariant that its v 
>   member always had 5 elements. X::~X() counted on that invariant, but 
>   the newly-introduced move constructor moved from v, thereby setting 
>   its length to zero.

I don't see why because we try to move X, `v` length would be zero

Comment: Btw, when you have full C++11 support you could write `y.emplace_back();`. No temporary, nothing to copy *or* move. But I realise the point of the example isn't how best to add an element to a vector, it's to illustrate what would happen if the temporary was moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem the article is trying to illustrate is that when an `X` is moved in the push_back, the invariant is broken. The temporary `X`'s vector `v` will be empty after moving, so the destructor call will invoke undefined behaviour. <strike>It could be that you see no problem because your compiler is not implementing move semantics, or because the undefined behaviour does not result in any perceptible runtime error through pure chance.</strike>

You can check this behaviour with this simple program, where we explicitly move an `X` instance:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct X {
  X() : v(5) {}
  std::vector<int> v;
};

int main() {
  X x0;
  std::cout << x0.v.size() << ", ";
  X x1 = std::move(x0);
  std::cout << x0.v.size() << "\n";
}
```

On GCC 4.7, these produce

> 5, 0

This comes from `std::vector`'s move constructor, which is used by `X`'s implicitly generated one. You can check `std::vector` directly:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> v0(5);
  std::cout << v0.size() << ", ";
  std::vector<int> v1 = std::move(v0);
  std::cout << v0.size() << "\n";
}
```

This produces the same output.

Now, in the example you quote, the presence of a **user defined destructor** means that there is no implicitly generated move constructor, so `X` is **not** moved in the `push_back`.

Comment: and why The temporary X's vector v will be empty after moving ?

Comment: @Guillaume07 because that is how move is defined for a vector.

Comment: @Guillaume07 there could be many reasons for that (the standard does not determine exactly what state the moved source should be, only that it should be a valid, deletable object) , but you certainly cannot count on that result. You should see it as some kind of interesting fluke.

Comment: Oops, ignore me, I was commenting on my misunderstanding of what you were saying is a fluke.

Comment: @SteveJessop but shouldn't `X` should have an compiler-synthesized move constructor?

Comment: @juanchopanza: your `X` does, the questioner's `X` doesn't, and that's what I got confused.

Comment: @Guillaume07 to be clear, my code should give `5, 0` according to the standard. Yours would produce `5, 5` because there is no implicitly generated move constructor, due to the user defined destructor.

Comment: MSVC10 does not implement compiler-generated move constructors.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see why because we try to move X, v length would be zero

Well, first of all we don't *try* to move the temporary `X()` in the push_back call. We *do* move it, or we don't[*].

If we were to move it (using an implicitly-generated move constructor), its data member `v` is moved. The assumption of the article is that moving from a vector leaves it empty, although I don't remember whether that's required or just typical. But it certainly does leave `v` in a state where it isn't guaranteed that you can access its former elements.

Remember, the whole point of moving is that it transfers expensive-to-copy resources from the source. So the temporary object is no longer guaranteed to have its internal array of 5 elements, because the destination of the move has taken it.

As to why it works in MSVC 2010 -- remember this code is presented in the article as an example just above "tweak #1 -- destructors suppress implicit move". C++11 does in fact contain this tweak -- no implicit move constructor is generated if there's a user-defined destructor (12.8/9). So the temporary is *not* moved, it's copied.

[*] Move or move not, there is no try. It's not up to the implementation whether or not to move it, the standard defines this.

Comment: implicit move constructor is generated if there's a user-defined destructor: yes indeed!

Comment: @Guillaume07: *no* implicit move constructor is generated if there's a user-defined destructor.

Comment: And even then, **VC2010 doesn't generate implicit move constructors and assignment operators**, anyway.

Comment: @Christian: ah, that would also explain it :-) Do you know, is it because they hadn't got around to it at the time, or because they believe the article linked here that implicit move is dangerous, and have decided to disobey the standard and never implement it?

Comment: @SteveJessop I think they're just missing it and it is already in VC11. I think I've read that it is a relic from times where the topic wasn't well decided for the final standard, so they just left it out in favour of correctness and backward compatibility. I guess they don't have any motivation to intentionally disobey the standard and are eager to follow it (no matter how it looks from the outside ;)).

Answer (score 1):

MSVC2010 does not implement auto=generated move constructors, so even if your code would have produced one, you won't see it there. Thus, as always, "random implementation X did Y" is a pretty meaningless statement to make.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010, the temporary will be be copied and then later destroyed. With move semantics, the temp object will simply be used for the vector.